# Django Pass parameters to Form, getting KeyError

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-errors

I'm trying to pass two parameters to initialize my form, I have tried different ways to achieve this but I get the same error over an over, this is the error that I'm getting (Traceback):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jorge.lopez\.virtualenvs\Carros-ZVuxKBiy\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\jorge.lopez\.virtualenvs\Carros-ZVuxKBiy\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\jorge.lopez\.virtualenvs\Carros-ZVuxKBiy\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\jorge.lopez\.virtualenvs\Carros-ZVuxKBiy\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\jorge.lopez\.virtualenvs\Carros-ZVuxKBiy\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 97, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\jorge.lopez\.virtualenvs\Carros-ZVuxKBiy\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 168, in get
    return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\jorge.lopez\.virtualenvs\Carros-ZVuxKBiy\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 133, in get
    return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data())
  File "C:\Users\jorge.lopez\.virtualenvs\Carros-ZVuxKBiy\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 66, in get_context_data
    kwargs['form'] = self.get_form()
  File "C:\Users\jorge.lopez\.virtualenvs\Carros-ZVuxKBiy\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 33, in get_form
    return form_class(**self.get_form_kwargs())
  File "C:\Users\jorge.lopez\Documents\Personal\Carros\carros\AC\forms.py", line 100, in __init__
    self.carro = kwargs.pop('carro')

Exception Type: KeyError at /payments/addtoexistingweek/1/2020-W07
Exception Value: 'carro'
```

**Update**

```
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /payments/addtoexistingweek/1/2020-W07
Exception Value: Reverse for 'pagoaexistente' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['payments/addtoexistingweek/(?P<carro>[0-9]+)/(?P<semana>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$']
```

> urls.py

```
path('payments/addtoexistingweek/<int:carro>/<slug:semana>',
         views.AgregarPagoSemana.as_view(), name='pagoaexistente'),
```

> views.py

**Update**

```
class AgregarPagoSemana(CreateView):

    template_name = "AC/add_paymentexistingweek.html"
    model = Pagos
    form_class = AgregarPagoTransaccionExistente

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(AgregarPagoSemana, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['carro'] = self.kwargs.get('carro')
        kwargs['semana'] = self.kwargs.get('semana')
        return kwargs
```

> forms.py

```
class AgregarPagoTransaccionExistente(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.carro = kwargs.pop('carro')
        self.semana = kwargs.pop('semana')
        super(AgregarPagoTransaccionExistente, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = Pagos
        fields = ('carro', 'pago', 'fecha', 'semana', 'renta')
        widgets = {'fecha': forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}),
                   'semana': forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'week'})
                   }
```

I don´t know if I'm understanding the error correctly and 'carro' is not getting the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the kwarg 'carro' to the view, but not to the form.

In your view, override the "get_form_kwargs" method and return the kwarg.

```
def get_form_kwargs(self):
    kwargs = super(InternalResetPasswordView, self).get_form_kwargs()
    kwargs['carro'] = self.kwargs.get('carro')
    return kwargs
```

Comment: Hi, I have updated my post: I tried you solution and I'm getting the NoReverseMatch, if I'm interpreting the error correctly is like the parameters are not being passed to the view?

Comment: NoReverseMatch is a different error. Likely something with your URLs. Without seeing the error, I can only guess, but try adding "success_url = '/'" to your view and see if that gets you past the error. If it does, then you will need to figure out what the correct URL should be for your site.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that.